# PHPStorm , Como mudar o nome de usuario?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Toda a vez que criamos um novo arquivo(file) ele nos dá um cabeçalho comentado com o nosso nick de usuário.
Como faço para mudar o nome do User? Procurei em todo o lugar na ferramenta e não encontrei!

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: claud
 * Date: 18/10/2016
 * Time: 01:05
 */
```

Grato pela colaboração.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129971/1518921)

Vá até <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>IDE Settings</kbd> > <kbd>File and Code Templates</kbd>

Então na aba <kbd>Includes</kbd> selecione <kbd>PHP File Header</kbd>.

Você poderá customizar ou remover, como desejar.

[image: phpstorm]